# Google Compute Engine - no resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

For the last 3 days, I've been trying to setup a VM instance using Google Compute Engine. However, every time I try, I get the following error:

> The zone 'projects/xxxxxxx/zones/xxxxxx' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

Am I doing something wrong or is Google not the company that I thought they were and they can't supply the hosting needs to customers?

Comment: Which region and zone are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage. Please review the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems) which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on Google Cloud Platform.